# Resizing Image in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, ide

Is there any way I can resize an image that I copy into my project, according the the size I need in pixels for example maybe I want to reduce the height and width by 100px then add it to my imageView or any other object. are there any tools that Xcode provide within the Xcode. I want to do it using interface without any programming so is there any way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer would be "NO".

I do not aware of any way to use Xcode resizing images.

The easiest method for me is to right click on any image and select "Open with External Editor". [Preview](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201740) should be opened and the app is quite simple to use.

Comment: external editors are always there as a second option but there should be a way XCode is a BIG platform ?

Comment: In Preview, click the "Markup Toolbar" button (pen pointing upwards), then the "Adjust Size" button (imbedded rectangles). Saving the image from Preview should change it directly in XCode

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are referring to the layout in storyboard/IB.

To get the native size of the image just select the image and press `Command + =` on the keyboard. the to re-size it proportionally select the corner and hold down the shift key when you re-size it.

Comment: no not in storyboard i want to change the actual size of the image.